# Write Service in OPCUA Is returning BadWriteNotSupported

Tags: opc-ua

I am using OPCUA .net client and server SDKs. I Created a Node in Server from client using AddNodes Service. The node is not attached to any Model in the server. Then i tried to Write a value(eg 121) to the node. The write returned [BadWriteNotSupported]. Is there something I am doing wrong

Comment: It is because that node's Access level or user access level is read-only.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you created read-only node. Download UA Expert and inspect the node, it is very handy tool for second check.

Comment: The node is not read-only. I have set the accessibility of the node to CurrentReadWrite, TimeStampWrite and StatusWrite. Write worked successfully if I set the Server Time stamp and Source Time stamp of the DataValue to DateTime.Min. But is there a way to set the Time stamps also.

Comment: @Siva, you cannot set timestamp of the server, this is whole point, server sets it to maintain coherent values. However you can set source timestamp, can be useful if you have one source of the values.

Answer (score 0):

It is because that node's Access level or user access level is read-only.

Mahe sure to set the access level and use access level for that now is read and write.

So that you can read and write a value to that node.